# call function between time intervals

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone

In app engine I would like to call a function if the current time is between a particular interval. This is what I am doing now.

```
ist_time = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=5, minutes = 30)
ist_midnight = ist_time.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
market_open = ist_midnight + timedelta(hours=9, minutes = 55)
market_close = ist_midnight + timedelta(hours=16, minutes = 01)
if ist_time >= market_open and ist_time <= market_close:
    check_for_updates()
```

Any better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you might want datetime's "time" type, which doesn't care about date.

```
import datetime
ist_time = datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=5, minutes = 30)
# Turn this into a time object (no day information).
ist_time = ist_time.time()
if datetime.time(9, 55) <= ist_time <= datetime.time(16, 1):
   ...
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to handle the timezone adjustment using tzinfo, but I have to confess I've never dealt with timezones.

Comment: is time(9,55) datetime.time or time.time?
couldnt pass 9,55 to either of them :(

Comment: It's datetime.time. I'll edit the answer to make that clearer.

I'm not sure why passing hour and minute as positional arguments wouldn't work, but you can keyword them: datetime.time(hour=9, minute=55)

Answer (score 1):

This is more compact, but not so obvious:

```
if '09:55' <= time.strftime(
   '%H:%M', time.gmtime((time.time() + 60 * (5 * 60 + 30)))) <= '16:01':
  check_for_updates()
```

Depending on how important it is for you to do the calculations absolutely properly, you may want to consider daylight saving time (use *pytz* for that -- it is possible to upload *pytz* bundled to your app to AppEngine) and seconds and millisecods as well (e.g. use `< '16:02'` instead of `<= '16:01'`, because the former doesn't depend on the second/subsecond precision.